# A quick question about keypress and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(document).keydown(function(e) {`

Well, that's my code - I was wondering if it is possible to have something like:

`$(document).not('#pinkElephant').keydown(function(e) {`

(Except, that doesn't work...)

Any Ideas?

Thanks very much!

p.s. All that function has inside it, is a `switch` statement.

**[edit]** Hey guys n gals - I cannot `return false;` because the element I need to type in is an `<input>` text, so the keyboard still needs to return here.

It's really confusing me :(

Comment: What is `pinkElephant`? Is it an input element? Or a container that holds several inputs?

Comment: the magical pinkElephant is an `<input>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternate way to do what you require by checking to see that the target element's `id` isn't `pinkElephant`.  Since this doesn't use the universal selector `'*'` it should perform better:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== "pinkElephant") {
        alert("I'm not pink!");
    }
});
```

**[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/hzeCz/1/)**

(updated from comment)

Comment: Ah, didn't account for that... +1 to jAndy's addendum

Comment: FYI: There's absolutely no need to use `.attr()` to get the ID of an element. Just do `e.target.id`.

Comment: Apologies, this works a treat. Not sure why I didn't vote and accept.

Comment: Thanks, but I think jAndy's last implementation is the best solution.  You should probably give the checkmark to him.

Comment: I would, but I won't for two reasons: 1) I'm using your solution and 2) as `#pinkElephant` is an input, there is nothing inside of it. Enjoy your points!

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to bind a `keydown event handler` to **all** nodes in your markup, with the exception of `#pinkElephant` you need to do it like this:

```
$(document).find('*').not('#pinkElephant').keydown(function() ..
```

or short

```
$(':not(#pinkElephant').keydown(function() ...
```

which implicitly uses the universal selector `*`.

Note, that this is never ever any good in terms of performance. I don't know your markup but I hope it's not very crouded using that kind of selector.

**update**

inspired by a comment, you could also do it like:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if( event.target.id === 'pinkElephant' || $.contains($('#pinkElephant')[0], event.target) )
        return false;

    // ...
});
```

Last snippet checks whether `#pinkElephant` itself or a child node was clicked and prevents the propagation + the default action. This is done by invoking `$.contains()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)</sup>

Comment: For better performance on large numbers of elements, why not just use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live)?

Comment: @MattBall: wouldn't even be necesarry in this case. It's just enough to bind one `keydown event handler` to the document (which `.live()` also does btw) and check for the `event target`.

Comment: I agree with @Matt, except that you don't really even need `.live()`. OP is already doing event delegation, so all that's really needed is to prevent bubbling.

Comment: That's true. So why not recommend that kind of solution, at least, rather than binding to n-1 DOM nodes?

Comment: @jAndy: Ultimately we don't know what `pinkElephant` is. Could be a container holding several elements.

Comment: @patrick: indeed - I updated with `.contains()` to be sure there.

Comment: Yes, it covers the lack of information in the question. Ultimately you'd use only one test or the other.

Comment: answer classification was upgraded to `supped`.

Comment: Indeed it was. Much improved. ;o)

Comment: I do apologise, #pinkElephant is an `<input>` :(

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't want elements inside `pinkElephant` to trigger the `keydown`.

Place a handler on `#pinkElephant` that stops propagation of the event.

```
$('#pinkElephant').bind('keydown',false);
```

*Note that passing `false` to `.bind()` requires jQuery 1.4.3 or later.*

If you're using an older version, do this:

```
$('#pinkElephant').bind('keydown',function(){return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(':not(#pinkElephant)').keydown(function(e) { 
    // ...
});
```